# Error while importing module in Turborepo with Drizzle ORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, turborepo, drizzle

I am working on a chat application project in which I am using Next.js and a separate server for socket connection. I am using Turborepo because I wanted to reuse Drizzle ORM and Shadcn code.

**Error**

This is occurring whenever I am importing any functions from `@repo/db` workspace. I was using commonjs, but authjs drizzle adapter is ESM module, so I had to switch to `"type": "module"`. I am facing error after that.

```js
node:internal/process/esm_loader:34
socket-server:dev:       internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
socket-server:dev:                                 ^
socket-server:dev: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/usr/Coding/personal-
projects/discord-turbo-og/apps/socket-server/node_modules/@repo/db/src/data-access/messages/create-message.js' 
imported from /home/usr/Coding/personal-projects/discord-turbo-og/apps/socket-
server/src/kafka/consumer.ts
```

[Line 21 causes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROWls.png)

#### socket-server

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "socket-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "dev": "TSIMP_DIAG=error node --import=tsimp/import src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@repo/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@repo/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsc-watch": "^6.0.4",
    "tsimp": "^2.0.11",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@repo/db": "workspace:*",

    //Other dependencies...
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["src", "*.ts", "**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true ,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

#### @repo/db

**package.json**

```json
  "name": "@repo/db",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "drizzle-kit generate:pg",
    "push": "node -r esbuild-register src/migrate.ts",
    "migrate": "node -r esbuild-register src/migrate.ts",
    "studio": "drizzle-kit studio"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/core": "^0.27.0",
    "@neondatabase/serverless": "^0.8.1",
    "@next/env": "^14.1.0",
    "adaptrs": "link:@auth/core/adaptrs",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.1",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.29.3",
    "esbuild-register": "^3.5.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@repo/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@repo/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.9",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.20.13",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfing.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "exclude": ["dist"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": ["src", "*.ts", "env.mjs", "**/*.ts"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

I tried to switch back to commonjs but failed. I tried to find similar question but was not able to find. I am new to development and this my first time working with Turborepo and Drizzle. Thank you in advance.